# How to easily show/hide some Parts of an iOS App for different versions of an app

Tags: ios, xcode, preprocessor, xcode4.2

I have an App for a client which is externally tested by another company (paid by the client) via TestFlight. After that the app goes to the Store. So as many of you know the Quality Assurance happens not only once. Mostly there are 3-4 approaches until the app is ready for the store.

In between I have to show my client the newest version of the app while the testing company is testing.

So I need to find an easy way to make different Versions with different parts visible in the app. Otherwise i have to manually hide the parts of the newer version everytime i have to build a new testVersion for the QA.

So as I dont want to repeat myself everytime, maybe there is a better way.

I tried to digg into the "preprocessor" Thing but didnt found any useful yet.

My Idea was to #define an app version but since I never used the preprocessors it`s quite hard for me to tell.

Hope you guys can help me out.
Thanks and Cheers Steven

EDIT:
I use SVN for my projects, But sadly I cannot "freeze" the QA Version hence I have to make changes related to the QA while make changes to the newest version of my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Quick ansewer - you can do it with preprocessor statements like :

If you have defined an app version like

```
#define APP_VERSION 5
```

You can do statements like

```
#ifdef APP_VERSION
  // Only if APP_VERSION exists
#endif

#if APP_VERSION > 4
  // Only for version 4 and above
#endif
```

---

2) Better answer

Use version control - take a look at git (and github.com)

You can use one branch for the code that you are submitting to the store and another branch for newer versions of the app.

Comment: Ahh ok so when I want to build forexample my newest version 2.1 I change the APP_VERSION to 2.1 in my prefix header and everything inside the #if APP_VERSION > 2.1 is going to be compiled while the compiler ignores everything in a statement like #if APP_VERSION < 2.1 ?

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly. (Though I'm not 100% sure what would happen if you started using decimal places but I assume it will still work - try it and see!)

Answer (score 1):

What you are wanting to do is a basic function of version control - You have frozen one version of your program (sent to QA) while you are developing another (showing your client).  This is called "branching" and almost every brand of version control handles it pretty well (I'm looking at you VSS!)

XCode directly supports two brands of version control [Git](http://git-scm.com/) and [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/).  Both will do the job you want, but they are totally different beasts.  Subversion is the old warhorse, while Git is the new shiny.

I'd suggest you read up on [XCode 4 Users Guide: Managing Versions of Your Project](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/SCM/SCM.html)

But if you want an even more basic introduction to version control I just found [A visual guide to version control](http://betterexplained.com/articles/a-visual-guide-to-version-control/)

Comment: If it would be such as easy I should say YES! :) but sadly I have some changes to make related to the QA, and some changes in the "developing" version. So the QA Version cannot be frozen. And of Course I use Version Control. I would NEVER go out without my SVN :) But thx anyways.

Comment: @Steven - I suppose I really meant that once you release a version to QA then you form a branch for the next version.  You can keep developing on QA and the new version independently, and then merge bug fixes from QA back into the new version.  If you are using svn for just checkin/checkout and reverting to previous versions then I don;t think you are using the its full power.

Answer (score 1):

As you use SVN, you normally just create a tag when you ship something to QA. As you said you can't do that, you would normally create a branch for your current developing version. Work in that branch will always is the latest effort. when you release to QA, you merge these changes into HEAD. Now, when you do changes to HEAD, they will automatically be combined back into your current development stuff when you merge them into HEAD again.

PS: With git, this is a lot easier than with SVN

Comment: This is actually a Point which is making me think about to switch to git for the future